# Movie about a shuttle hunted by another alien shuttle

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

The movie plot is about a shuttle traveling in space when the crew spots a dark floating shuttle. The crew decides to attach to it to search for any human lives in danger.

So volunteers step inside this abandoned shuttle and return claiming no one was on the shuttle, later we understand that one of volunteers was hunted by aliens (We see no alien before), and he/she tries to hunt another crew and each dead crew becomes hunted and tries to do the same to others.

I can't remember the exact date it was from, but it was likely the late 90s or early 2000s. I watched it on local TV.

Comment: I recommend visiting https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and reading the [tour] to get some ideas on how you can improve your question.

Comment: Like was it on TV? DVD? The Theater? What did the alien look like before it started using bodies as disguise? How does it kill them? Did it look like practical effects? CG? Were the crew mostly white? Multiracial? Some aliens themselves?

Comment: @hessam hedieh - In roughly which year did you watch this movie? I know you said you think it was from the late '90s or early 2000s, but did you watch it that long ago, or more recently?

Comment: @LogicDictates, I watched it long time ago, maybe in 2005, give or take

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Crew of a spacecraft discovering an apparently abandoned spaceship that contains a mysterious presence that starts to kill them sounds like the premise of the 1990 movie [*The Dark Side of the Moon*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099364/).

Per the [plot summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Side_of_the_Moon_(1990_film)#Plot):

> In the near future, a maintenance vehicle is orbiting the Earth on a mission to repair nuclear-armed satellites. Suddenly, the crew experiences a mysterious, inexplicable power failure that cannot be accounted for. As the ship grows colder, they find themselves drifting toward the dark side of the Moon. **An old NASA shuttle, the Discovery, drifts toward them,** although NASA has not been operating for 30 years.
>
> Two of the crew members board the ship, hoping to salvage parts to repair their ship, but instead they find a dead body. The mission records of the crew's own ship indicate that the shuttle they have found disappeared in the Bermuda Triangle many years before. The area in space the shuttle is found in corresponds to the earthbound Bermuda Triangle.
>
> As they attempt to solve this mystery, it quickly becomes apparent that a malevolent force has been waiting on the NASA shuttle, using the aforesaid dead body as its host. **It now begins to stalk the crew members one at a time.** As they fight the force, it becomes apparent they are facing the devil.
>
> With time, air and power running out, the captain decides to make the ultimate sacrifice.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like  Even Horizon
Wikipedia summary
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Horizon_(film)

When the Event Horizon, a spacecraft that vanished years earlier, suddenly reappears, a team is dispatched to investigate the ship. Accompanied by the Event Horizon's creator, William Weir (Sam Neill), the crew of the Lewis and Clark, led by Capt. Miller (Laurence Fishburne), begins to explore the seemingly abandoned vessel. However, it soon becomes evident that something sinister resides in its corridors, and that the horrors that befell the Event Horizon's previous journey are still present.
[image][image]

Comment: tnx for comment, definitely a good movie, but during weekend i watched The dark side of the moon and it was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Glad you found the movie